# mock value inside the component file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing

I would like to ask if I have the variable `useState` in the component which is used as a condition that determines the element inside it will appear or not. How to mock the variable? So that I can test the element inside the condition if the value is 'login'.

```
   const [dataHistory,seDataHistory] = useState("")
   const [data,setData] = useState("firstTimeLogin")
        
    const func2 = () => {
     getData({
      item1: "0",
     }).
     then((res) => {
       funct();
     })
   }

   const funct = () => 
     {setData("login")}
        
   return  
     {data === "firstTimeLogin" && (
        <div><button onClick="funct2()">next</button></div>
     )}

     {data === "login" && (
        <div>flow login</div>
      )}
```

Comment: where is your trigger point for `funct` in your JSX?

Comment: Im sory, i have update my question. It display the first element inside 'firstTimeLogin' then after click it will prompt element inside 'login'. I dont know how to change the value so that it will print element inside 'login'

Comment: your `getData` is an internal function in your component too? I'm trying to figure out all your implementation for a possible help :D

Comment: ya thanks2.. function getdata() is a function from other file which is import in that component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to add `data-testid` for your button

```
{data === "firstTimeLogin" && (
   <div><button onClick="funct2" data-testid="next-button">next</button></div>
)}
```

*You called `onClick="funct2()"` which is to trigger `funct2` immediately after re-rendering, so I modified it to `onClick="funct2"`.*

*Note that you also can use `next` content in the button for the event click but I'd prefer using `data-testid` is more fixed than `next` content.*

In your test file, you should mock `getData` and call `fireEvent.click` to trigger `funct2()`

```
import { screen, fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react';

//'/getData' must be the actual path you're importing for `getData` usage
jest.mock('/getData', () => {
   return {
      getData: () => new Promise((resolve) => { resolve('') }) // it's mocked, so you can pass any data here
   }
})

it('should call funct', async () => {
   render(<YourComponent {...yourProps}/>)
   const nextButton = await screen.findByTestId("next-button"); //matched with `data-testid` we defined earlier
   fireEvent.click(nextButton); //trigger the event click on that button
   const flowLoginElements = await screen.findByText('flow login'); //after state changes, you should have `flow login` in your content
   expect(flowLoginElements).toBeTruthy();
})
```

Comment: get error getData is not a function. why ya?

Comment: i do like this..
.
.
jest.mock('/getData', () => {
   return {
      getData: new Promise((resolve) => { resolve(mockData) })
   }
})
.
.
my function at other file look like this
export function getData(): Promise<getDataParam>{
  return fetchGetData('GET', getServer().data,{})
}

Comment: Ah my badd! it should be `getData: () => new Promise((resolve) => { resolve('') })` @syareen

Comment: ady solve the promise error... but the element inside the 'login' doesnt prompt..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button and onClick of the button call funct()

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question about testing. When asked for more info about their jsx code in a comment on they question, they modified the question to show they're already doing what you suggest.